# IONIC Firebase PUSH Notifications bug at iOS 13

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, notifications, push

after updating to iOS 13 and XCode 11.2.1, the event of PushNotification registration is never fired anymore.

```
PushNotifications.addListener(
    "registration",
    (token: PushNotificationToken) => {
       console.log(token);
    }
```

Comment: please provide plugin details

Comment: Its working again. I think Firebase was down at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, Firebase was down at the moment. Some minutes after publishing here all the Notifications came together.